# Auth0: .NET6 winforms app not working as expected when setting "Browser = new WebViewBrowserChromium()" is used in Auth0 configuration

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0, auth0

We have a .NET6 based winforms application to which we have integrated Auth0.

What is the requirment?
When the winforms app is started, a login screen should be displayed with a button. When user clicks this button, users credentials should be passed automcatically from Auth0 to MS Azuree AD and it should get validated from MS Azure AD. The login screen from MS Azure should not show the user id field and password field.

What has been done so far?
1: A connection between Auth0 and MS Azure AD has been created
2: Auth0 code has been integrated and option Browser = new WebViewBrowserChromium() has been configured in the code.
3: When application starts, Auth0 login page appears with a  button (Auth0 to Azure connection)
4: When button is clicked, a screen comes from Azure asking us to key in domain user name and password.
5: After keying in the data, user gets authentication againts MS Azure AD  and user is able to successfully login.

What is the issue?
The login screen from Azure where user has to key in the credentials.

What we want?
When application starts, Auth0 login page appears with a  button (Auth0 to Azure connection)
When button is clicked, ***screen should not come from Azure*** asking to key in user crednetails, instead it should auotomatically login the user using that connection.

- Hints

Following are the three options which can be used:-
Browser = new WebBrowserBrowser()
// Use IE (IBrowser contained within Auth0 SDK)

Browser = new WebViewBrowser()
// Use Edge (DEFAULT Auth0 setting - Will revert to IE if run as admin)

Browser = new WebViewBrowserChromium()
// Use Edge Chromium (requires MS Edge Webview2 be installed)

When I use 1st option, I am getting the desired functionality but when I use 2nd or 3rd, I am not getting the desired functionality. We cant use 1st option as IE would be removed from the desktops in next 1-2 months time.

Any pointers would be helpfull.

best regards,
SP